# How to attach relationships in existing nodes in neo4j?

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, relationship

I'm trying to make a graph from a csv file, but I'm not being able to add additional relationship in the existing nodes.

My actual code is:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000
LOAD CSV FROM 'my_file.csv' AS line
MERGE (p:Title { title: line[0]})

MERGE (a:Author { name: line[1]})
MERGE (a)-[:COLABORATE_IN]->(p)

WITH line  WHERE line[2] IS NOT NULL
MERGE (b:Author {name: line[2]})
MERGE (b)-[:COLABORATE_IN]->(p) //not working 

RETURN line[2]
```

It should be a simple, It creates well the nodes and the firsts relationships, but for the line[2] it just create the relationships for new nodes. What could I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything that is not piped in the `WITH` clause is not available to the next part of the query :

```
MERGE (a:Author { name: line[1]})
MERGE (a)-[:COLABORATE_IN]->(p)

WITH line  WHERE line[2] IS NOT NULL
// p is no more available here
```

Just add the `p` identifier to make it available in the remaining part of the query :

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000
LOAD CSV FROM 'my_file.csv' AS line
MERGE (p:Title { title: line[0]})

MERGE (a:Author { name: line[1]})
MERGE (a)-[:COLABORATE_IN]->(p)

WITH p, line  
WHERE line[2] IS NOT NULL
MERGE (b:Author {name: line[2]})
MERGE (b)-[:COLABORATE_IN]->(p) //not working 

RETURN line[2]
```